# Wildcard DNS with URI Request

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

So here is my problem. I want to redirect name.domain.com/trips/1 to domain.com?username=name&trip=1 using modrewrite. Is this possible? I have the dns set up correctly however - I am unsure about the htaccess file. Can I link all this information to one PHP or do I need to create a directory for every user?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd should do it with **mod_rewrite**:

```
Redirect permanent ^([a-z]+).*/([0-9]+)$ domain.com?username=$1&trip=$2
```

This will pick up things like

```
bob.domain.com/trips/1
ted.domain.com/trips/123
```

And translate them to:

```
domain.com?username=bob&trip=1
domain.com?username=ted&trip=123
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What about if the user adds the www piece to the front?

Comment: That you will need to treat separately.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have either to link or to create, as you already have domain name in PHP
see `phpinfo(32);` for more info

so, the only thing you need is redirect all trips to index, very usual task and SO has many solutions already I am sure.